# Using nohup at /etc/init.d/service

Tags: shell-script, services, daemon

I have been trying to create a daemon using `/etc/init.d/myservice` and it will call a shell script that contains `nohup` within the script line.

Will it affect it if I could do `service stop` later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nohup just blocks SIGHUP.  The rc script to start or stop your daemon could use any signals at all to shut down your process.

[This link](http://www.enderunix.org/docs/eng/daemon.php) has a good overview of the things a daemon process needs to do on startup, for example closing `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, detaching itself from the parent and getting a new process group and setting up signal handlers.

Comment: I had managed to throw in nohup within the shell script and the start up part works OK.

But when i do /sbin/service myservice stop, the following output shown on the screen even the service did stopped successfully.

`/sbin/service: line 66: 19466 Terminated env -i LANG="$LANG" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ${OPTIONS}`

Comment: Incidentally, a lot of daemons nowadays interpret SIGHUP as a command to reload their configuration files. This might be a better use for it than `nohup`.

Comment: Your wrapper script should redirect stdout and stderr to a log file, and a daemon process should close stdin, stdout and stderr anyway.  See the edit for a link to the ins and outs of writing a daemon process.

Answer (score 5):

You can check this script I wrote recently, it should help:

https://gist.github.com/Radamanf/7152723